MORE DETAILED explanation of ERROR: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B6
Here are screenshots from my spreadsheet that has the issues I discussed in the previous question:

IMPORTRANGE(,) works in a single cell, however, when adding the same formula to the next cell in the column (only changing the data source from Sheet1 to Sheet2), the error occurs:

Later tries with changing the column to a row has worked. However, I'd rather not change the inherent structure of my spreadsheet.

This not a discussion forum. If there are details missing from the other question they should be added there (I've just edited it with your screenshots). Your question was answered. Q: Why the error?  A: There's data in the formula's spill range (in the way) Q: How to get rid of the error? A: Move the data out of the way or move the formula. If you have additional   questions they should differentiate themselves and include sample data, formula(s) and expected results in markdown text format.

Besides showing that the sheet has merged ranges, the images are not enough to provide the missing details. Show the formulas as text and any other detail required to reproduce the problem.
